# Unchecked ThrowingSupplier for lambdas

Tags: java

How could I wrote a ThrowingSupplier with an unchecked method that could replace this part of code? I have really no idea how to start with it should it be an interface or rather a class.

```
        try {
            // get connection with the database
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(e);
        }
```

What I would like to get is something like

```
Connection connection = ThrowingSupplier.unchecked(dataSource::getConnection).get();
```

Any ideas how should it looks like? I am not sure if it should be an interface or a class I tried to wrote that, but then I could not create a static method unchecked and I would not to create new instance of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you want:

```
public class ThrowingSupplier {
    public static <T> Supplier<T> unchecked(Callable<T> callable) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                return callable.call();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(e);
            }
        };
    }

    // example usage:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataSource dataSource = null;
        Connection connection = ThrowingSupplier.unchecked(dataSource::getConnection).get();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to check that the callable is not `null` (e.g. by using `Objects.requireNonNull`) before returning the supplier. Otherwise a `null` callable will be noticed way too late and possibly at a completely unrelated place.